# How to change the check state of a check box from custom action (WIX)

Tags: wix, custom-action, wix3.10

I have a dialog which has a check box. I want to change its check state depending on the value set to a property in the custom action. How to do this ? I am new for WIX.

```
 <Control Id="folderCheck" Type="CheckBox"  X="15" Y="205" Height="10" Width="200" Property="FOLDEREXISTS" CheckBoxValue="1" Text="Folders exist."/>
```

What I want to be done is, If I set the FOLDEREXISTS property to "0", I want this check box to be unchecked in the dialog. Please provide code examples

Comment: I don't if this is possible to do, but wouldn't it be easier to add some extra configuration depending upon the settings used during installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply set a value for FOLDEREXISTS property within the custom action code, and publish this property in a previous action or an event within WIX.